# can another topology be given to $\mathbb R$ so it has the same continuous maps $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples, continuity

We say two topologies $\tau$ and $\rho$ on $X$ are similar if the set of continuous functions $f:(X,\tau) \rightarrow (X,\tau)$ is the same as the set of continuous functions $f:(X,\rho)\rightarrow (X,\rho)$.

Does there exist a topology $\tau$  that is similar to the euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$?

This was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890383/is-there-another-topology-on-mathbbr-that-gives-the-same-continuous-functio/1890409#1890409) but all we could prove is that $\tau$ must be a refinement of the euclidean topology.

Regards.

Comment: It seems that if you can show that $\tau$ is a refinement of $\rho$, then $\rho$ is a refinement of $\tau$. Is there something special about the Euclidean topology that breaks this symmetry?

Comment: The proof used the construction of the Euclidean topology from the subbasis of sets of the form $(-\infty, a)$ and $(a, \infty)$, so it was specific to the Euclidean topology, not a general fact.

Comment: A question on "similarity": Assume $\tau''$ is a refinement of $\tau'$, which in turn is a refinement of $\tau$ with $\tau$ similar to $\tau''$. Is it necessarily true that $\tau'$ is also similar?

Comment: Never mind, my question clearly has the answer  "no", by considering the discrete and indiscrete topologies.

Comment: You can ask this question for any topological space.  I believe there is a standard answer in most of the standard point-set topology textbooks.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am very interested in knowing what the standard answer is.

Comment: I am surprised by the vote to close. @RyanBudney, I am also curious about the standard answer, which I have certainly not seen before . . .

Comment: @RyanBudney I agree with the original poster and Noah. In particular I'd be curious to know if there is a comprehensible criterion for an arbitrary space. It's certainly not unique in general (e.g., the example of user44191 of the indiscrete versus discrete topology).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only topology similar to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the Euclidean topology.

---

Suppose there is such a topology $\tau$. I'll use "open," "continuous," etc. to mean with respect to the Euclidean topology and "$\tau$-open" etc. for $\tau$.

Since $\tau$ is a refinement of the Euclidean topology, there exists a point (without loss of generality $0$) and a $\tau$-open neighborhood $U$ which does not contain any open interval containing $0$. Then there is a sequence $x_i$ in the complement of $U$ converging to $0$. For convenience choose a monotonic subsequence $y_i$, without loss of generality positive, and suppose $y_1=1$.

Now consider the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which fixes the complement of $(0,1)$, takes $[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}]$ to $y_n$, and takes $[\frac{1}{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n}]$ to $[y_{n+1},y_n]$ linearly. This function is continuous, hence $\tau$-continuous.

Then the preimage of $(-1,1)\cap U$ is a $\tau$-open subset $V$ of $(-1,0] \cup \bigcup_n (\frac{1}{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n})$ which contains $0$.

There is a homeomorphism (hence a $\tau$-homeomorphism) $\phi$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which fixes the complement of $(0,2)$, takes $[1,2]$ to $[\frac{1}{2},2]$ linearly, and takes $[\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k}]$ to $[\frac{1}{k+2},\frac{1}{k+1}]$ linearly.

Then $\phi(V)\cap V$ is a $\tau$-open subset of $(-1,0]$ containing $0$.

But then $(-\infty,0]$ is $\tau$-open, so that $\mathbb{R}$ is not $\tau$-connected, a contradiction since then there is a $\tau$-continuous map sending $(-\infty,0]$ to one point and $(0,\infty)$ to another.

Answer (score 15):

This is a special case of much more general results surveyed in the book
MR0393330 Magill, K. D., Jr. A survey of semigroups of continuous selfmaps. Semigroup Forum 11 (1975/76), no. 3, 189–282.

For example, Theorem 2.3 of this book says that only the abstract semigroup structure
(with respect to composition) of the set of continuous maps is sufficient to
recover the topology.

Comment: How can what you say be correct, when, as mentioned, the trivial and discrete topologies give the same set of continuous functions?

Comment: Okay, I see there are some conditions in this theorem. The spaces have to be "generated" (see Definition 2.2).

Comment: Real line is "generated":-)

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is "generated", but it is not obvious to me (without answering the above question) that $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ is "generated".

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure this theorem really answers the general question of when, given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ there is another topology $\tau'$ on $X$ with the same continuous functions.